# En RoR no se me esta ejecutando el codigo .coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Me encuentro disenando una red social y deseo que cuando el usuario pase el click sobre alguno de sus post aparezca la opcion de editar o eliminar el mismo, dichas opciones se encuentran e un div, y lo que pretendo hacer se puede realizar con un style y con el archivo .coffee de la siguiente manera:
en style tengo lo siguiente:

/*lo que igue es para que no se visualice las opciones de editar y eliminar*/
.status .admin{
  display: none;
}

/*cuando la accion del hover ocurra dentro de la seccion admin*/
/*funciona con js, y asi, se vean las opciones de editar y eliminar*/
.status.hover .admin{
  display: inline;
}

ahora bien, en un archivo llamado, statuses.coffee tengo lo siguiente:
$ ->
    $('.status').hover (event)->
    $(this).toggleClass("hover")

pero esto no me esta funcionando, ciertamente no se ven las opciones edit ni eliminar, pero cuando paso el click el alguno de los post no me aparecen dichas opciones.
Si creen que se puede hacer de otra manera sin usar el archivo .coffee seria de gran ayuda, aunque prefiero que se pueda trabajar con el mismo, pues mas adelante, seguamente voy a necesitar hacer uso del mismo. muchas gracias

Comment: Coffeescript es un lenguaje que por si mismo no tiene soporte de ejecución si no que necesita un transpilador (babel o traceur). Desconozco si hay una gema que haga ésto en background sin tener q transpilar a JS.

Answer (score 0):

Posibles soluciones:

- Lo más básico, pero ¿Has agregado `coffee-rails` a tu `Gemfile`?
- ¿Has revisado que el javascript generado en tu explorador efectivamente aparece el código que escribiste?
- ¿Como estás agregando tu código a tu archivo coffeescript? Lo usual es hacerlo como sigue:

> ```
>  $(document).ready ->
>     // Tu código
> ```

De todas formas, lo usual es que si tienes un problema, debes agregar tu código. Así que si nada de esto resuelve tu problema, agrega tu código, porque con la información que das, no es suficiente para resolver tu problema.

Comment: Si verifique mi lista de gemas y entre ellas esta coffee-rails(4.1.1), coffee-script (2.4.1) y coffee-script-source (1.10.0), verifique que si ejecutara el codigo js, pues en el archivo application.js agregue un alert("ddd"); y cuando ejecuto en el servidor me carga la pagina con un mensaje con ddd. Me encuentro desarrollando una red social y quiero que cuando el usuario pase el click sobre un div de los post aparezca la opcion de editar el post y para ello pretendo hacer uso de style y el archivo .coffee. Voy a editar mi pregunta  con parte del codigo. leela y dame tu opinion por favor.